# Pandas Iterate through rows, compare column value with string in a list, return a value from another column

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

Currently I am trying to iterate through a data frame, compare each value in a list of strings with the value in a certain column in the data frame. If this is comparison is true, then append the values from a different column of the same row to a separate list.

```
list_of_words = 'yes', 'no', 'maybe'
appendList = []
    for word in list_of_words: 
        for row in dataframe1.iterrows():
            if row['A'] == word:
                appendList.append(row['B'])
                return appendList
```

The issue is I am unsure how to compare the value in the list with the column value. I am quite new to pandas and python in general but so far the convenience methods have been great. Just unsure how to work this to return what I need. Any help or advice to any docs that would help would be appreciated!

Comment: `dataframe1[dataframe1[‘A’].isin(list_of_words)][‘B’].tolist()` ?

Comment: Thank you Chris A! That worked perfectly. Now I have a list that I can then use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
list_of_words = ['yes', 'no', 'maybe']

appendList = dataframe1.B[dataframe1.A.isin(list_of_words)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, each `row` is a 2-element tuple, which is indexed using an integer: `row[0]` is the row number and `row[1]` is a [pandas.Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html). So it is a TypeError to use the expression `row['A']`.

```
>>> row['A']
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

You can convert a `pandas.Series` into a normal python list containing elements of that row using [pandas.Series.tolist()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html#pandas.Series.tolist) and then do your comparison:

```
for row in dataframe1.iterrows():
    row_data = row[1].tolist() 
    if row_data[0] == word:
        appendList.append(row_data[1])
```

Being a list, `row_data` must be indexed using an integer. This makes your code less readable.

Comment: I have that running now, I'll keep you updated. Thank you